# Can one get the name of the parent border, or tab?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to log some info in our system, and to make it easily readable, I need to log the names of the container a specific check box is in.

For example, I have a check box in a panel, then the panel is a tabbed pane. I would like to log "tab name/panel border name/check box name"

This seems to prove difficult. I have the check box, and then does a `getParent()`, but I don't seem to get much further than that.

### Update

By name I meant the name shown at the top of tab; Actually I have a number of different containers, and I need to log all of their names (not the actual name given by the programmer, but the name displayed on the GUI). So for a `JPanel`, it would be a border name, and for some other container it would be something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "name"?

Comment: [container.getComponents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponent%28int%29) returns an array of JComponents, you have to test for `if ( instanceof JWhatever )`

Comment: By 'border' DYM a [`TitledBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html) & by 'name of tab' DYM the text shown in the selector tab at the top (by default) of the tabbed pane?

Comment: By "Name at the top"  I mean the name shown at the top of the component, when the GUI is displayed. So for a JPanel, i would like the border name, and for a JTabbedPanel, I would like the name of the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aiming for the following is quite trivial using reflection and methods of the Swing/AWT API:

- The check box text.
- The (title of the) titled border of the panel in which the check box is displayed.
- The title of the tab displaying the panel.

[image]

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class PrettyPrintControlChange {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    static final String rightwards = new String(Character.toChars(8594));

    PrettyPrintControlChange() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        ui.add(tabbedPane);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 45);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                textArea.append(getPrettyCheckBoxString(cb) + "\n");
            }
        };

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) { //tabs
            JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));
            tabbedPane.addTab("Tab " + i, tabPanel);
            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) { // panels with titled border
                JPanel titledPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 4, 4));
                titledPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Panel " + j));
                tabPanel.add(titledPanel);
                for (int k = 1; k < 7; k++) { // check boxes
                    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check Box " + k);
                    checkBox.addActionListener(al);
                    titledPanel.add(checkBox);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Provides a string representing the state and containment hierarchy of a
     * check box. Uses the text of the check box, titled borders and tabbed pane
     * tab in which the check box appears to identify it.
     */
    private static String getPrettyCheckBoxString(JCheckBox cb) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Check Box: ");
        ArrayList<Container> containerHeirarchy = new ArrayList<Container>();
        containerHeirarchy.add(cb);

        Container parent = cb.getParent();
        boolean foundTabbedPane = false;
        while (parent != null && !foundTabbedPane) {
            if (parent instanceof JTabbedPane) {
                foundTabbedPane = true;
            }
            containerHeirarchy.add(parent);
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        // traverse the collection in revers order.
        for (int i = containerHeirarchy.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Container c = containerHeirarchy.get(i);
            if (c instanceof JTabbedPane) {
                JTabbedPane tp = (JTabbedPane) c;
                String title = tp.getTitleAt(tp.getSelectedIndex());
                sb.append(" tab: " + title);
            } else if (c instanceof JPanel) {
                JPanel panel = (JPanel) c;
                Border border = panel.getBorder();
                if (border instanceof TitledBorder) {
                    TitledBorder titledBorder = (TitledBorder) border;
                    String title = titledBorder.getTitle();
                    sb.append(" " + rightwards + " panel: " + title);
                }
            } else if (c instanceof JCheckBox) {
                JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox)c;
                String title = checkBox.getText();
                sb.append(" " + rightwards + " check box: " + title);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void prettyPrintCheckBox(JCheckBox cb) {
        System.out.println(getPrettyCheckBoxString(cb));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                PrettyPrintControlChange o = new PrettyPrintControlChange();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, this is a perfect example, and has helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

The container (returned by `getParent()`) is an AWT `Component`, and has a `getName()` method that returns the component's notional name.  However, I think you will find that the name field is normally `null` ... unless you have gone to the effort of setting it earlier.

On the other hand, if you want to get the classname for the container, you can get it by calling `parentObj.getClass().getName()`.

---

> By name I meant the name shown at the top of tab.

Well I don't think there is a generic way to do that.  What you are thinking of as the "name" of a component could be a variety of different things, depending on what the component is.  It may not even be a part of the parent object.

Some component classes have a `getText()` method, that might be suitable to use as a name.  Others have nothing suitable.

Comment: Well, sorry if I tipped on some toes, I hardly ever use StackOverflow, and this question is one of the rare occasions.

Comment: @Harriet - You didn't step on toes.  However, it is important to be clear in the questions you ask.  Vague questions are difficult to answer ... because we often can't figure out what the OP is actually asking.